# Load discrete view from table view?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a table view that I want to segue to specific views when a specific cell is selected. For example, if the cell at index 0 is selected, I want the "RedViewController" to be visible.

The example I keep receiving looks something like this (located in the VC with the table view)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? RedViewController {
            if let blogIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {
                destination.blogName = swiftBlogs[blogIndex]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Where blogName and swiftBlogs are random examples)

But this just loads specific data into a singular view controller. Preferably I want a switch statement for each index path that makes a specific VC visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to Duncan C and a little more research!

In the table view VC I added the handy function

```
func switchToViewController(identifier: String) {
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as! UIViewController
    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: false)
}
```

And in the didselectRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let selectedRow = indexPath.indexAtPosition(indexPath.row)

    switch selectedRow {
    case 0:
        switchToViewController("RedVCIdentifier")
    default:
        println("Unknown Cell selected")

    }
}
```

But also had to add a Storyboard ID to the RedViewController in the storyboard as "RedVCIdentifier"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so write your code that way. Don't link your table views directly  with a segue. Instead write code in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

In that method you can write a switch statement, or use an array lookup, to load a view controller using a unique ID and the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, or trigger a through code using performSegueWithIdentifier.